# Android SQLite query to return rows that contains certain text

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I need a sqlite query for my local DB that returns all the rows of a table that contains a certain String in a column. The issue is I only have part of that String.

```
ID  COLUMN1   COLUMN2    COLUMN3
1  myString11111  timestamp   some_value
2. myString22222  timestamp   some_value
```

So in the example above I only know `myString` which is only part of the content of COLUMN1.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
String myQuery = "select * from " +  MY_TABLE + " where " + COLUMN1 + " LIKE ? " + "' " + myString + " '";
```

Using this query throws an exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "' foo '": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from my_table where COLUMN1 LIKE ? ' foo '
```

Does anyone know is is possible to retrieve rows if only part of the content is known?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `?` place holders for the parameters there is no need to concatenate them. You can pass them in the 2nd argument of the `rawQuery()` method:

```
String myQuery = "select * from " +  MY_TABLE + " where " + COLUMN1 + " LIKE '%' || ? || '%'";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(myQuery, new String[] {myString});
```

where `db` is an instance of `SQLiteDatabase`.
The query will return all the rows that contain the value of the string `myString` in the column `COLUMN1`.
You can do the same with the function `INSTR()` instead of the operator `LIKE`:

```
String myQuery = "select * from " +  MY_TABLE + " where instr(" + COLUMN1 + ", ?)";
```